# Is there anywhere to “hook” the creation of a SQL Server connection?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

This is a long shot, but is there any way to get some of my code to run every time a `SqlConnection` is created in my application?  I can’t think of Ado.net events that are fired on connection creation, but I may have missed one.

(Otherwise I will have to add this to a small number of code paths in our data access layer and hope it get added to any newly created code paths.)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Any kind of logging?

Comment: @Yves, I wish to add a check on the state of some "flag" in the database, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095216/how-can-i-tell-when-i-am-given-an-un-cached-sqlserver-connection that has some more background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a connection factory that all your requests route to this code so you can add your code here, or by overriding SqlConnection constructor and hiding default constructor.

Comment: Factory Pattern is surely what i would go for as well! Maybe add some rule to FxCop to catch any code that instantiates the SqlConnection outside of your factory class.

Comment: This is a new code base to me, I hope to find a connection factory I can use, however I asked this question so I could have a "plan b"

Answer (score 0):

There is a `StateChange` event on the `SqlConnection` class that you can hook into to be notified when its state changes (from `closed` to `open` or back).

Check out the [relevant MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: The problem is I need to hoot the creation of the connection object to be abel to subscribe to that event.